# How to edit shape keys with the armature deformation in needed position?

Tags: shape-keys

Maybe for all these years I've been missing something but, is it correct that in blender you just can't edit a shape key when the mesh is deformed by an armature? It's almost like a pleasure denial that whenever you wanna edit your shape key, your character model just snap back to rest pose, and then you're like: what was it that I'm fixing?

I hope someone can come and call me stupid and I've been missing something for all these years.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you use this button in modifiers?

[image]

I think, this is that you are searching for.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Oh GOD YES thank you you saved my pathetic life!!! I knew I was just too stupid to figure that out!!!

Answer (score 0):

I found it useful to save my rigged pose in Stl and then bring it back to Blender to convert it to SVA.  It took me hours to figure this out.  I come from non tech background.